# Flutter FutureProvider is not found when trying to use its contents in ListView

Tags: listview, flutter, async-await, future, provider

guys, Flutter beginner here. I'm reading a json in the app start with a FutureProvider but when I try use it to load a ListView I get the message "Could not find the correct Provider above this Consumer", but it's declared and loaded above MaterialApp. I tried use Consumer and Provider.of but neither works.
A detail: I want to share the json content between all the pages in routes.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Selecao()),
        FutureProvider<List>(
          create: (_) async => DocumentoProvider().loadDocumentoData(),
          lazy: false,
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: HomePage(), // route for home is '/' implicitly
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          // define the routes
          ApresentacaoPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) =>
              ApresentacaoPage(),
          CatecismosPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) => CatecismosPage(),
          DocumentosPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) => DocumentosPage(),
          IndicePage.routeName: (BuildContext context) => IndicePage(),
          SobrePage.routeName: (BuildContext context) => SobrePage(),
          PesquisaPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) => PesquisaPage(),
          ConteudoPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) => ConteudoPage(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My FutureProvider:

```
class DocumentoProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final String _dataPath = "assets/data.json";
  List lista = new List();

  Future<List> loadDocumentoData() async {
    var dataString = await loadAsset();
    lista = json.decode(dataString);

    print('leu provider');
    // print(lista);
    // notifyListeners();
    return lista;
  }

  Future<String> loadAsset() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString(_dataPath);
  }
}
```

And the HomePage trying to load the lista property from my futureprovider:

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // var documentos = Provider.of<DocumentoProvider>(context, listen: false);
    // var lista = documentos.lista;
    // print(lista);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("CONFE"),
      ),
      drawer: Menu(),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Consumer<DocumentoProvider>(
            builder: (context, documentos, child) => ListView.builder(
              key: ObjectKey(documentos.lista[0]),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      titleSection(documentos.lista[index]),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
              itemCount: documentos.lista == null ? 0 : documentos.lista.length,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I just read and watched lots of tutorials but I can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Consumer<DocumentoProvider>` inside `HomePageState` is looking for the wrong object type.

Your Providers in `MyApp` are providing two types:

- `Selecao`
- `List`

```
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Selecao()),
        FutureProvider<List>(
          create: (_) async => DocumentoProvider().loadDocumentoData(),
          lazy: false,
        )
```

But in `HomePageState` you're trying to Consume a `DocumentoProvider`

```
 body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Consumer<DocumentoProvider>(
```

I think this should be:

```
 body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Consumer<List>(
```

---

***Unrelated*** side note - I don't think think you need `async` here:

```
        FutureProvider<List>(
          create: (_) async => DocumentoProvider().loadDocumentoData(),
```

Since `loadDocumentData()` is defined as an async function inside `DocumentoProvider`